# Calculating the number of characters inside a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I made a list with some character in it and I looped through it to calculate the number of a specific character and it returns the number of all the characters inside the list and not the one's that I said it to. Take a look at my code and if someone can help I will appreciate it!

This is the code:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
sum_of_as = 0
for i in array:
    if str('a') in array:
        sum_of_as += 1
        
print(f'''The number of a's in this array are {sum_of_as}''')
```

Comment: The problem in your code is that `if str('a') in array` looks at the whole array each time. You want something like `if array[i] == 'a':`. A shorter way to do this would be to use a list comprehension:
`sum_of_as = len([x for x in array if x=='a'])`

Comment: You can change array to i in
 if str('a') in array: 
Resulting: if str('a') ==i:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the list is only ever going to contain single letter strings, as per your example, or if you are searching for a word in a list of words, then you can simply use

```
list_of_strings = ["a", "b,", "c", "d", "a"]
list_of_strings.count("a")
```

Be aware though that will not count things such us
`l = ["ba", "a", "c"]` where the response would be 1 as opposed to 2 when searching for `a`.

The below examples do account for this, so it really does depend on your data and use case.

```
list_of_strings = ["a", "b,", "c", "d", "ba"]
count = sum(string.count("a") for string in list_of_strings)
print(count)

>>> 2
```

The above iterates each element of the list and totals up (sums) the amount of times the letter "a" is found, using `str.count()`

`str.count()` is a method that returns the number of how many times the string you supply is found in that string you call the method on.
This is the equivalent of doing

```
count = 0
list_of_strings = ["a", "b,", "c", "d", "ba"]
for string in list_of_strings:
    count += string.count("b")
print(count)
```

```
name = "david"
print(name.count("d"))

>>> 2
```

Comment: @StergiosKatseas I fleshed out the answer for you with more explanation

Answer (score 0):

The `if str('a') in array` evaluates to `True` in every for-loop iteration, because there is `'a'` in the `array`.

Try to change the code to `if i == "a":`

```py
array = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]

sum_of_as = 0
for i in array:
    if i == "a":
        sum_of_as += 1

print(sum_of_as)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

---

OR:

Use `list.count`:

```
print(array.count("a"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I don't understand is that the "i" will loop through the whole list and that list consists of 5 characters and 2 'a' characters. So, how does the '''if str('a) in array''' evaluates to True? Thanks for the comment again!

Comment: @StergiosKatseas `if str('a') in array:` evaluates to True because you have 'a' inside the list. The `in` operator checks for the presence of `a` in the array.